# Persistent HTML form data across sessions

Tags: web-application, web-browser, javascript, html, storage

I'm currently testing an application which appears to have a somewhat persistent HTML form data storage, yet I don't understand how.

- UserA logs in
- Fills form with custom data
- Logs out before sending form
- UserB logs in
- Finds form with custom data from UserA

The same browser is shared by both users. The form data is never sent to the server and not in the local storage, session storage, cookies, cache storage or the indexed DB (from Firefox's developer tools "Storage" tab).

The form data even persists if the browsers "Clear all history" is used to clear all caches/settings/....

Closing the browser appears to delete the stored form data.

Looking at the DOM, I see attributes like `__reactEventHandlers` and `__reactInternalInstance` for the form, so I'd assume that there is a React JavaScript-foo doing something to retain the data.

How exactly can data be stored like this and more importantly, how can this be prevented?

Comment: Are UserA and UserB logging from different workstations? Are you 100% sure that no data is sent to the server, in any form?

Comment: Have you recorded the transferred data with a web proxy? Have you considered the use of websockets?

Comment: @n0idea sorry, I should have specified that. Both use the same browser.

Comment: @EuphrasiusvonderHummelwiese yes, I'm using a proxy to check if anything is sent. No websockets are used either.

Comment: @GarlicCheese What if you're searching in the wrong place? Maybe it is some sort of **browser functionality** (form auto-fill or similar)? I know you've specified that the form data persists when "Clearing all history", but as an example Chrome browser just has a dedicated checkbox to empty form auto-fill data.

Comment: @n0idea valid idea there, but no form auto-fill occurs for me.